Debug MAUI iOS AOT crash
How can I debug a crash when AOT is enabled for an iOS MAUI app? Specifically, I'm looking for the .NET call stack. The AOT debug instructions show how to attach LLDB to the app, but not what to do next.
I used these commands in lldb to break the debugger at the crash:
device select <udid>
device process attach -n <app>
breakpoint set --name objc_exception_throw
process continue

From there, I tried clrstack, but got this error:
Failed to find runtime module (libcoreclr.dylib), 0x80004005
Extension commands need it in order to have something to do.
For more information see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135652
ClrStack  failed

In AOT, does the CLR stack (or anything CLR) even apply? If not, for a published app, where do I find the call stack for my crashing .NET code?
